# How to convert two arrays in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have two ararys. Array_1 and Array_2. I need to find which values from array_1 are found and correspond to the values of array_2. Every single time I find a match, a checkbox is checked. How can I compare two arrays?

```
var array_1 = ["area_dust_surface", 
               "area_dust_furniture", 
               "area_dust_baseboard",
               "area_dust_ceiling"];

var array_2 = ["area_dust_surface", "area_dust_furniture",
               "area_dust_baseboard","area_dust_ceiling",
               "area_vaccum_carpets", "area_vaccum_mop_floors",
               "area_dust_windows", "area_dust_pictures",
               "area_dust_lamps", "area_dust_mirrors",
               "area_empty_trash", "bath_dust_surface",
               "bath_dust_windows", "bath_dust_cabinets",
               "bath_clean_shower_tubs", "bath_clean_toilets",
               "kitchen_dust_chairs", "kitchen_dust_baseboards",
               "kitchen_dust_fridge_top", "kitchen_clean_out_fridge",
               "kitchen_clean_counters", "kitchen_clean_door_knobs",
               "kitchen_clean_light_switch", "kitchen_clean_sinks",
               "kitchen_clean_microwave", "kitchen_clean_dishwasher",
               "kitchen_clean_kitchen_table",
               "kitchen_vaccum_mop_floor", "kitchen_empty_trash",
               "bed_dust_surface", "bed_dust_furniture_top",
               "bed_dust_surface", "bed_dust_baseboards",
               "bed_dust_door_panels", "bed_dust_windows",
               "laundry_1", "laundry_2", "laundry_3", "laundry_4",
               "laundry_5", "inside_oven_cleaning",
               "inside_refrigerator_cleaning",
               "inside_washer_machine_cleaning",
               "sterilize_washing_machine", "changing_bed_sheets",
               "accessible_windows_cleaning"];

if(jQuery.inArray(array_1, array_2) !== -1){

//do something

}
```

Comment: @freedomn-m: no that's not it at all. I'm not trying to make a union. I'm trying to find matches.

Comment: You're correct - my bad - should have been this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript

Comment: I don't think he met intersection, but the items in 1 that are in 2 (not that intersect) @freedomn-m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the following:

```js
var array_1 = ["area_dust_surface", 
               "area_dust_furniture", 
               "area_dust_baseboard",
               "area_dust_ceiling"];

var array_2 = ["area_dust_surface", "area_dust_furniture",
               "area_dust_baseboard","area_dust_ceiling",
               "area_vaccum_carpets", "area_vaccum_mop_floors",
               "area_dust_windows", "area_dust_pictures",
               "area_dust_lamps", "area_dust_mirrors",
               "area_empty_trash", "bath_dust_surface",
               "bath_dust_windows", "bath_dust_cabinets",
               "bath_clean_shower_tubs", "bath_clean_toilets",
               "kitchen_dust_chairs", "kitchen_dust_baseboards",
               "kitchen_dust_fridge_top", "kitchen_clean_out_fridge",
               "kitchen_clean_counters", "kitchen_clean_door_knobs",
               "kitchen_clean_light_switch", "kitchen_clean_sinks",
               "kitchen_clean_microwave", "kitchen_clean_dishwasher",
               "kitchen_clean_kitchen_table",
               "kitchen_vaccum_mop_floor", "kitchen_empty_trash",
               "bed_dust_surface", "bed_dust_furniture_top",
               "bed_dust_surface", "bed_dust_baseboards",
               "bed_dust_door_panels", "bed_dust_windows",
               "laundry_1", "laundry_2", "laundry_3", "laundry_4",
               "laundry_5", "inside_oven_cleaning",
               "inside_refrigerator_cleaning",
               "inside_washer_machine_cleaning",
               "sterilize_washing_machine", "changing_bed_sheets",
               "accessible_windows_cleaning"];
               
               
const itemsInArray2FromArray1 = array_1.filter(k => array_2.includes(k))

console.log({itemsInArray2FromArray1})
```

Comment: That is brilliant sir. Let me test this now.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through the larger of the arrays, and check if each item is included in the other array. This can be done in multiple ways or possibly reversed, but the gist of it is:

```js
const array_1 = ["area_dust_surface",
  "area_dust_furniture",
  "area_dust_baseboard",
  "area_dust_ceiling"
];

const array_2 = ["area_dust_surface", "area_dust_furniture",
  "area_dust_baseboard", "area_dust_ceiling",
  "area_vaccum_carpets", "area_vaccum_mop_floors",
  "area_dust_windows", "area_dust_pictures",
  "area_dust_lamps", "area_dust_mirrors",
  "area_empty_trash", "bath_dust_surface",
  "bath_dust_windows", "bath_dust_cabinets",
  "bath_clean_shower_tubs", "bath_clean_toilets",
  "kitchen_dust_chairs", "kitchen_dust_baseboards",
  "kitchen_dust_fridge_top", "kitchen_clean_out_fridge",
  "kitchen_clean_counters", "kitchen_clean_door_knobs",
  "kitchen_clean_light_switch", "kitchen_clean_sinks",
  "kitchen_clean_microwave", "kitchen_clean_dishwasher",
  "kitchen_clean_kitchen_table",
  "kitchen_vaccum_mop_floor", "kitchen_empty_trash",
  "bed_dust_surface", "bed_dust_furniture_top",
  "bed_dust_surface", "bed_dust_baseboards",
  "bed_dust_door_panels", "bed_dust_windows",
  "laundry_1", "laundry_2", "laundry_3", "laundry_4",
  "laundry_5", "inside_oven_cleaning",
  "inside_refrigerator_cleaning",
  "inside_washer_machine_cleaning",
  "sterilize_washing_machine", "changing_bed_sheets",
  "accessible_windows_cleaning"
];

function array_intersect(source, target) {
  const output = [];
  for (const a of source) {
    if (!output.includes(a) && target.some(i => i === a)) {
      output.push(a);
    }
  }
  return output;
}

for (const exists of array_intersect(array_2, array_1)) {
  console.log('needs to be checked ON:', exists);
}
```